# Looking for php (or other convertable) array of cell phones

Tags: php, mobile-phones

I'm looking for a array of cell phones, prefer PHP but I can convert any kind to PHP.

Something like this for example:

```
 array('iPhone','Blackberry','Samsung Galaxy','LG');  //and many more
```

I'm looking for one that has keywords that would be included in a HTTP_USER_AGENT call.

Is there anything on the market or in Github that I might use as a starter.

I'm not looking for mobile devices like kendal, I just want the phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mobiledetect library: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: Yes thanks :) i had that on the list, i was hoping for something already pre sifted alittle as i really dont want all mobile just the phones.  But yes ill have to sift through that and create one if there is not one already done.

Comment: I guess one way would be to shop for popular phones and that should give me the basics right, and then i can google the samples of agent and get some keywords built.

Comment: You can check out the source code and get the list of mobile phones: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php

Comment: Thanks yeah looking into that now... :)